# Oracle OCI, is session based connection possible instead of connection for each transaction

Tags: php, oracle, session, connection, oracle-call-interface

I will design a web application in which the application will make some transactions in an Oracle DB with OCI.

My question is, should I connect every time when I need a transaction on the database side with oci_connect which means I will need to put to every php file a connection string. Or is there a way to create a one time connection (a session) and make everytime the transactions over that connection.

Comment: Just because you only need to connect to the DB as required, doesn't mean you need to put a connect string into every PHP file that requires a connection. Have you thought about encapsulating the database connection behavior into a class that you can reuse throughout your application?

Comment: Thank you for the advise. But I meant, as far as I know the cost for connection to the database is high. I am trying to find a way to work as fast as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was Database Resident Connection Pooling in oracle. It is supported after 11g.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/whatsnew/php-scalability-ha-twp-128842.pdf

Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP) provides a connection pool in the database server for typical Web application usage scenarios where the application acquires a database connection, works on it for a relatively short duration, and then releases it.